# Adjustment of progressBar on R flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

Good day all,

I will like to adjust the size of my progressBar as shown here:

[image]

I will like them to be thicker in height and width.

I have googled around for the past few hours and can't seem to find a solution specific to flexdashboard in R.

This is my code:

```r
# Progressbar UI
    progressBar(id = "test", value = Pre_treat_done, total = Pre_treat_total, display_pct = T, title =   df_new$WORK_NO[1], status = "warning")
    
    
updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "test", value = Pre_treat_done, status = "warning")
```

I have tried the following

1. Added tags$style customisation

```
tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML('
        #test {height: 100px;
              width: 800px;
              position:fixed;}
        ')))
```

That does not work as intended. I am wondering if there is a need to use CSS for this customization and will appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by including the following line in my existing code:

```r
fluidPage()
```

That resulted in this:

[image]